# Adding headers to comma delimited string using Python 3.4

Tags: python, mysql, sql, database, string

I have a static output from a serial connection which is comma delimited. The incoming data will always have 23 values.

data string from machine:

**# "987654321      ","               ","               ", .00, .00, .30, .06, .35, .50, 2.00, .50, .00, .00, .00, .00, .00, .00, .00, .00, .00, .00, .00, 3.71**

```
import serial

con=serial.Serial('COM4',115200)

while 1:

    if con.inWaiting():

        val = con.read(con.inWaiting())

        if len(val)> 1 :
            stra = val.decode("utf-8")
```

I receive the data and can view the data to verify it's correct. I'm lost when trying to add column header to the string so that data can be inserted into a database

I'm using a Raspberry Pi to run the program between the machine and database

The column headers:
Batch ID, Sub ID, Grand ID, Value4, Value5, Dime, Penny, Nickel, Quarter, Dollar, Half, Value12, Value13, Value14, Value15, Value16, Value17, Value18, Value19, Value20, Value21, Value22, Total

The database on the Raspberry Pi will be MySQL which will be uploaded to SQL Sever when the unit is connected to the network

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any header in your CSV file while importing it into your MySQL. Actually, MySQL would not understand any header if you push that header to it, you would need to tell MySQL to skip that line anyway.

Just follow this manual: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html